# App does not fit on anything but an iPhone (Plus Models)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing my entire application programmatically and for some reason when running my app on either an iPhone 6 Plus, 7 Plus, or 8 Plus simulator everything fits perfectly with no black bars but when running in an iPhone non plus model or iPhone X the black bars appear on the top and bottom of the screen.

I did not have this issue before, any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: Are you using a launch screen storyboard or launch images?

Comment: Yes I have a launch image

Comment: You have *a* launch image? You need many launch images, one for each possible device size. Instead of launch images, use a single launch screen storyboard. So much simpler.

Comment: Your were right! Thank you so much!